# ngModel not updating when using input type date

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but here is what I'm trying to accomplish. I only care about google chrome as this is for debugging purposes. I want to use the html5 input type date and have it update a model. The problem comes in that if i select a date from the popup angular doesn't update it. If I instead use the arrows to run through dates it then updates it. Is there some other way to get the ngModel to update?

```
<div ng-app>
     <input type="date" data-ng-model="date" style="width:200px;" />
     <br>
     {{ date }}
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/55/

Comment: It seems to work in Chrome 35 and Angular 1.3.0 beta. What versions are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular listens to the `input` event which seems to trigger when you click mouse up/down or click the errors. For some reason though (bug?) that event doesn't trigger from the calendar dialog.

I created simple directive which registers to the `change` event and then updates the model. You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r4PkFbvk9xJmMEGEoSD9?p=preview).

The directive is quite simple:

```
module.directive('dateFix', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            element.on('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
                });         
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And then use it like this: `<input type="date" ng-model="dateValue" date-fix />`

A temporary workaround at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
     <input type="date" name="date"  data-ng-model="date" style="width:200px;" />
</form>
```

and you have the value in : **form.date.$viewValue**;